# How can we know which configuration formed from a set of $n$ angles that sums to $(n-2)\pi$ can form an equilateral polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygons

Given a set of $n$ angles: $\{A_0,A_1,.....,(n-2)\pi-\sum_0^{n-2}A_i\}$

How can we determine which ordering from this set can form a consistent linear equilateral shape ?

For instance $\{2\pi/3,\pi/4,\pi/4,5\pi/6\}$ how can we discriminate this set from this peculiar ordering if it has an ability to form a quadrilateral shape ?

I tried bruteforcing all permutations of sets but I'm sure there should be some system of constraints that tightens number of trials at a significant level.

What I have thought of, beginning from smallest values , constant checking if the actual angle doesn't early-close the polygon or generate an out-of-shape like this: 
[image]

I constructed a [geo-applet](https://www.geogebra.org/m/G5bUTJNA) to simulate what i'm trying to do, for 4 angles the constraint is obvious, 2 per 2 angles should be equal, 5 angles and above I don't know it should be way tricky to grasp.

Comment: Well, usually no orderings will work.

Comment: Draw the angels in a circle and you will get your polygon.

Comment: @Moti edges formed by a circle drawn polygon can not be of same length.